# Difference between WebStorm and PHPStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm choosing an IDE for web development and I would like to know what the differences between WebStorm and PHPStorm are.

I couldn't find any major points on JetBrains' website and even Google didn't help that much.

All I know now is that PHPStorm doesn't support JS like WebStorm, but is able to due to plugins. Is this the only difference?

Answer (score 542, accepted):

> I couldn't find any major points on JetBrains' website and even Google didn't help that much.

You should train your search-fu twice as harder.

FROM: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

> **NOTE:** PhpStorm includes all the functionality of WebStorm (HTML/CSS Editor, JavaScript Editor) and adds full-fledged support for PHP and Databases/SQL.

[Their forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&topic=200367219&query=phpstorm+and+webstorm) also has quite few answers for such question.

---

Basically: **PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Database support**

WebStorm comes with certain (mainly) JavaScript oriented plugins bundled by default while they need to be installed manually in PhpStorm (if necessary).

At the same time: plugins that require PHP support would not be able to install in WebStorm (for obvious reasons).

**P.S.**
Since WebStorm has different release cycle than PhpStorm, it can have new JS/CSS/HTML oriented features faster than PhpStorm (it's all about platform builds used).

**For example:** latest stable PhpStorm is v7.1.4 while WebStorm is already on v8.x. But, PhpStorm v8 will be released in approximately 1 month (accordingly to their road map), which means that stable version of PhpStorm will include some of the features that will only be available in WebStorm v9 (quite few months from now, lets say 2-3-5) -- *if using/comparing stable versions ONLY*.

**UPDATE (2016-12-13):**
Since 2016.1 version PhpStorm and WebStorm use the same version/build numbers .. so there is no longer difference between the same versions: functionality present in WebStorm 2016.3 is the same as in PhpStorm 2016.3 (if the same plugins are installed, of course).

---

> Everything that I know atm. is that PHPStorm doesn't support JS part like Webstorm

That's not correct (your wording). Missing "extra" technology in PhpStorm (for example: node, angularjs) does not mean that *basic JavaScript support* has missing functionality. Any "extras" can be easily installed (or deactivated, if not required).

---

**UPDATE (2016-12-13):**
Here is the list of plugins that are bundled with WebStorm 2016.3 but require manual installation in PhpStorm 2016.3 (if you need them, of course):

- Cucumber.js
- Dart
- EditorConfig
- EJS
- Handelbars/Mustache
- Java Server Pages (JSP) Integration
- Karma
- LiveEdit
- Meteor
- PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin
- Polymer & Web Components
- Pug (ex-Jade)
- Spy-js
- Stylus support
- Yeoman

Comment: There can be some things that PhpStorm doesn't have that Webstorm does, e.g. being able to set a remote node interpreter.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi `Node.js Remote Interpreter` plugin (made by JetBrains)? -- *"Allows to configure Node.js interpreters for remote environments; run, debug, and profile Node.js applications remotely (currently working only though SSH)"*

Comment: @LazyOne even with that it doesn't work. There was a small conversation I had with one of the PhpStorm people, and they confirmed that indeed remote node.js works properly in WebStorm only, and there was a Jetbrains ticket for making sure the remote node.js interpreter worked with PhpStorm too, not just WebStorm.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi Where **exactly** did you try to specify that remote interpreter. It's available for Run/Debug configurations only -- see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25411 . Or you have some another scenario? if so -- please comment that ticket.

Comment: @LazyOne is that correct that if I install all plugins from *UPDATE (2016-12-13)* I get totally functional of `WebStorm` with `PhpStorm` features? And what you can say about [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647004/difference-between-webstorm-and-phpstorm/25647482#27337593)?

Comment: BTW -- native DB support in WebStorm may appear later this year (based on the comments in appropriate ticket on WebStorm Issue Tracker)

Comment: "for obvious reasons" - it's not obvious to me why you can add JS plugins to PhpStorm, but cannot add PHP plugins to WebStorm...

Comment: Upvote for  _Basically: PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Database support_

Comment: @Rikki, that's simple WebStorm is "less" advanced IDE and PhpStorm is "more" advanced (automatically more expensive). If you are giving some free bonuses to your users, you prefer to give them to the ones who spend more money, additional form of advertisement, a.k.a. business model. TBH I would do exactly the same. If someone asks me from which to start I always suggest PS before WS, even if at the moment they do not plan to use the "advanced programming IDE" it's just better invest.

Answer (score 25):

Essentially, PHPStorm = WebStorm + PHP, SQL and more.

**BUT** (and this is a very important "but") because it is capable of parsing so much more, it quite often fails to parse Node.js dependencies, as they (probably) conflict with some other syntax it is capable of parsing.

The most notable example of that would be Mongoose model definition, where WebStorm easily recognizes *mongoose.model* method, whereas PHPStorm marks it as unresolved as soon as you connect Node.js plugin.

Surprisingly, it manages to resolve the method if you turn the plugin off, but leave the core modules connected, but then it cannot be used for debugging. And this happens to quite a few methods out there.

All this goes for PHPStorm 8.0.1, maybe in later releases this annoying bug would be fixed.

Comment: PHP Storm doesn't have liveEdit  default.

Answer (score 18):

There is actually a comparison of the two in the official [WebStorm FAQ](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+FAQ).  However, the version history of that page shows it was last updated December 13, so I'm not sure if it's maintained.

This is an extract from the FAQs for reference:

> ### What is WebStorm & PhpStorm?
>
> WebStorm & PhpStorm are IDEs (Integrated Development Environment)
>   built on top of JetBrains IntelliJ platform and narrowed for web
>   development.
>
> ### Which IDE do I need?
>
> PhpStorm is designed to cover all needs of PHP developer including
>   full JavaScript, CSS and HTML support. WebStorm is for hardcore
>   JavaScript developers. It includes features PHP developer normally
>   doesn’t need like Node.JS or JSUnit. However corresponding plugins can
>   be installed into PhpStorm for free.
>
> ### How often new vesions (sic) are going to be released?
>
> Preliminarily, WebStorm and PhpStorm major updates will be available
>   twice in a year. Minor (bugfix) updates are issued periodically as
>   required.
>
> snip
>
> ### IntelliJ IDEA vs WebStorm features
>
> IntelliJ IDEA remains JetBrains' flagship product and IntelliJ IDEA
>   provides full JavaScript support along with *all* other features of
>   WebStorm via bundled or downloadable plugins. The only thing missing
>   is the simplified project setup.

Answer (score 2):

> PhpStorm supports all the features of WebStorm but some are not bundled so you might need to install the corresponding plugin for some framework via Settings > Plugins > Install JetBrains Plugin.

[Official comment - jetbrains.com](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206578639/comments/207578829)

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience, even though theoretically many JetBrains products share the same functionalities, the new features that get introduced in some apps don't get immediately introduced in the others. In particular, IntelliJ IDEA has a new version once per year, while WebStorm and PHPStorm get 2 to 3 per year I think. Keep that in mind when choosing an IDE. :)

Comment: How is this related to the question? The OP asked about the difference between WebStorm and PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

I use IntelliJ Idea, PHPStorm, and WebStorm.  I thought WebStorm would be sufficient for PHP coding, but in reality it's great for editing but doesn't feel like it real-time-error-checks PHP as well as PHPStorm.  This is just an observation, coming from a regular user of a JetBrains products.

If you're a student try taking advantage of the free license while attending school; it gives you a chance to explore different JetBrains IDE...  Did I mention CLion?  =]