# AngularJs - Run Visual Studio 2015 project in Webstorm?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, webstorm

Is it possible to run AngularJs project that was created in Visual Studio 2015 in Webstorm? My partner and I were doing the project in AngularJs. However, I am now unable to open his project in my VS 2015 due to database problem 'connection string specifies an instance of SQL Server that is not installed'. After almost 1 week I am still unable to solve the problem thus would like to ask if it is possible to run AngularJS project created from VS in Jetbrain Webstorm?

Comment: In WebStorm you may just use `Open` action and point to the project root folder -- it will open it as brand new WebStorm project using those files.

Comment: how about the database created earlier in VS 2015? It also can be used in Webstorm?

Comment: WebStorm itself has no DB or SQL support -- you may want to use PhpStorm or any other more-advanced IDEA-based IDE that have built-in DB support (e.g. [PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB support](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119)). Or you can use 3rd party plugin (DB Navigator) to manage/browse your DB.

Comment: i have tried DB navigator but it still doesnt work. Does phpstorm using Xampp?

Comment: It comes with simple built-in web server (you will notice it by 63342 port in URL).. but can easily use your own web server (be it Apache from XAMPP or whatever). Configuration of XAMPP is up to you -- IDE will not touch/configure Apache for you so you will have to make sure that Apache can serve your files.

Comment: I may suggest you these few links to look trough: 1) http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials 2)  https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Tutorials 3) http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ 4) http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: Thanks for your help @LazyOne :D