# How to run PhpStorm and WebStorm in a single directory?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I am currently working on a project which requires PhpStorm and WebStorm to work in a single directory. However, the issue is that their respective `.idea` directories collide.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: First of all -- why do you need **both** PhpStorm & WebStorm exactly? Simply speaking: **PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB** (just some plugins that are bundled with WebStorm out of the box must be installed in PhpStorm manually -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119 ).

Comment: But if you **really** need it ... keep project settings (`.idea` subfolder) in another/separate location for each IDE (which means that you will have to configure project twice). It's simple and described in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170102