# How to add Laravel plugin to WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

Recently I installed WebStorm. I wanted to use it for Vue and Laravel projects. I tried to add Laravel plugin to work with, but in plugin description it is said that I need to

> active it per Project under "Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Laravel"

The problem is that I have no "PHP" option to choose among Languages & Frameworks.

How to install it to my WebStorm application?

Comment: the description uses then PHPStorm

Comment: Should I install PHPStorm? I thought that all languages are included in WebStorm.

Comment: Do what @lena said -- you need PhpStorm. [PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Database support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119). WebStorm offers no support for PHP and therefore Laravel plugin cannot be made functional there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webstorm provides no support for PHP, and Laravel plugin is not compatible with it. You need PHPStorm for working with PHP. It [includes](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/) all Webstorm stuff for javascript, HTML, CSS, etc., so you won't lose any functionality

Answer (score 0):

download the pluguin here :
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel-plugin

- Install plugin and active it per Project under "Settings > Languages
  & Frameworks > PHP > Laravel"
- Use "Laravel IDE Helper Generator" to    generate ide classes
- Configure root Views directory, if not    usingdefault file
  structure
- (Enable autopopup for completion in    pluginsetting)

Comment: this is not the answer to my question - sorry. I installed this plugin, but I'm unable to activate it because I haven't got PHP option in my Settings > Languages & Frameworks

Comment: did you still have the problem ?