# PhpStorm syntax problem with Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, phpstorm

I have a problem with Angular project and syntax of TypeScript, I make a new empty Angular project but PhpStorm (2019.2.1) don't recognize TypeScript syntax.

[image]

Comment: Why dont use vscode ? Phpstorm meant for PHP development. Vscode have rich support for all language

Comment: @TonyNgo PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119

Comment: @danny36 Based on the file icon alone .. it suggests that this file is treated as XML file. **1)** Ensure that JavaScript and TypeScript plugin is actually enabled **2)** Check `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types` -- look under "XML" file type -- ensure that no unusual pattern is present there (bottom list for that file type).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `.ts` extension is assigned to **XML** file type in **Settings | Editor | File Types**. Please remove all `.ts` patterns from this file type and make sure that `*.ts` is listed among patterns registered for **TypeScript**:

[image]

Comment: thank you this is the problem. I have ad .ts to xml file for a another project but phpstorm make this setting global.

Comment: file type settings are IDE-wide, there is no way to re-assign patterns for particular project only

Answer (score 0):

For Angular and other JS,TS based Web development I recommend using :

- Webstorm , it's by Jetbrains, same as PHPStorm
- Visual Studio Code

However, if you follow these steps, you should not face such issue:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/angular.html

Also, as in comments by LazyOne: [PhpStorm syntax problem with Angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921262/phpstorm-syntax-problem-with-angular-project/57921390#comment102260825_57921262)

Comment: PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB. Some plugins needs to be installed manually/separately. Please check this link before making such statements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119

Comment: So why is the OP facing this issue?

Comment: Possible broken settings or accidental misconfiguration. `.ts` files getting recognized just fine here out of the box.

Comment: I too found that is completely supports Angular, thanks for pointing out, answer updated,