# Getting a "Project components were changed externally and can not be reloaded" when switching between PyCharm and WebStorm

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a project that has some Python code and some React code, so I like to work on the Python parts in PyCharm and the web parts in WebStorm. However, whenever the two are open at the same time and I switch windows, I'm getting the following error:

```
Project 'monkey' components were changed externally and cannot be reloaded:

com.intellij.coverage.CoverageDataManagerImpl

Would you like to reload project?
```

[image: error from pycharm]

It doesn't matter if I press `yes` or `no`, the error still persists.

Any idea of settings I should tweak/files I need to delete to stop the behaviour from happening?

**WebStorm version**: WebStorm 2019.3, Build #WS-193.5233.80, built on November 25, 2019

**PyCharm version**: PyCharm 2019.3.4 (Professional Edition), Build #PY-193.6911.25, built on March 18, 2020

Comment: 1) You cannot open the same project in different IDEs as they both use the same `.idea` subfolder to store the settings. And if you modify stuff in one IDE another will treat it as external modification and that's why it wants to reload it all (primarily for data consistency reasons). You may workaround this by having different project settings for different IDEs and storing them in different places -- see workaround in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170102

Comment: 2) Most importantly -- **why do you need 2 IDEs?**. PyCharm Pro has all functionality of the WebStorm included (same with PhpStorm: = WebStorm + PHP + DB https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119). Sure, some plugins must be installed manually .. and WebStorm may have a bit lighter settings, but functionality wise it's all there.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/web_development.html : "**Frontend** Modern web applications have grown complex with sophisticated JavaScript frameworks and tools. **PyCharm Professional bundles WebStorm**, giving best-in-class client-side development."