# Can Develop full MERN stack project in PyCharm?

Tags: javascript, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, mern

I checked the JetBrains site and saw that PyCharm Pro have JavaScript support.

Can I develop JavaScript only project in PyCharm Pro? Like a MERN stack project just with PyCharm. Or do I need to get WebStorm as well?

Comment: You can develop anything even in the free Community edition, it just may not have full syntax highlighting, type checking etc. for Javascript…

Comment: I believe [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/javascript-specific-guidelines.html#ws_js_start_existing_app) might help you.

Comment: @deceze Yes and No. The FREE Community edition does not support web dev features much so Pro edition needed if the actual support for those technologies is required. See https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Pro version has all functionality of WebStorm, you just need to install certain plugins manually. (PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + database; https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119. Similar story with PyCharm Pro) From https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/web_development.html "Frontend Modern web applications have grown complex with sophisticated JavaScript frameworks and tools. **PyCharm Professional bundles WebStorm**, giving best-in-class client-side development."

Comment: @LazyOne So pycharm pro has everything and can do what webstorm can. Thanks for this.