# How Do I Run a Node.js Application in PhpStorm with Query Strings in URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a Node.js project in PhpStorm that runs the `index.js` file just fine when I click the Run command, but now I need to run that with query strings in the URL (e.g. `index.js?q=query`) and get the query string parameter using something like `req.query` in Express. Problem is I am new to PhpStorm and cannot figure out how to run the scrips with parameters in the URL.

So far I only see the option to run the `index.js` file but no option to run `index.js?q=query`. Normally I would just load the script in a browser but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a headless browser and it would require me to copy the application from the PhpStorm project file to a directory in XAMPP.

If I run a command like `node index.js` it works fine but if I change that to `node index.js?q=query` I get an error saying "Error: Cannot find module"

I am also not sure if I am using the right syntax for accessing the query parameters via Express.

```
const express = require('express')
const exp = express();
const url = exp.req.query.url;
const keyword = exp.req.query.q;
const source = exp.req.query.source;
```

Comment: PHP Storm is an odd choice of IDE for writing Node.js code with, but it doesn't have to be used to write PHP.

Comment: @Quentin [PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647482/783119). Why it's odd (to use an IDE that supports more than one language), even if it's primarily focused on another lang (but fully supports the required language anyway)?

Comment: PhpStorm allows people to create node.js projects just like they can create a php project.

Answer (score 1):

> Normally I would just load the script in a browser

While the JavaScript programming language got its start as a client-side language, it is a **general** purpose language.

If you are using the `express` module, then it **replaces** your webserver and other server side language. It **can't** run inside the browser.

(Note that in your example code, you never start the Express server. See [the Hello World example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) in Express' documentation).

You can't run your script and provide it with a URL as one operation. You need two operations:

1. Run your script to start the server
2. Issue an HTTP request to it (for example via a browser, curl, or another script).

If you wanted to write unit tests for an Express server then that gets into fairly complex territory with lots of options. See [this page](https://livebook.manning.com/book/express-in-action/chapter-9/109) for example.